# How to proccessing Vuex array in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I'm a new web developer. I need help getting all of the titles from all of the objects in an array. I get an array of products from an axios request. In the next step I need to process this array in a Vue component and record a single value to data. Next I need to display this data value in a multiselect's options.

Here is the axios code:

```
async getOrders(ctx, data)
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios({
            url: '/orders',
            data: data,
            method: 'GET'
        })
            .then((resp) => {
                ctx.commit('setOrders', resp.data.orders)
                ctx.commit('setUsers', resp.data.users)
                ctx.commit('setProducts', resp.data.products)
                ctx.commit('updatePagination', resp.data.pagination)
                resolve(resp)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
                reject(error)
            })
    })
},
```

This is my array of products recorded in Vuex store

```
0: {id: 6, category_id: 2, title: "Test", brand: "Тест", serial_number: "2165412315864",…}

1: {id: 7, category_id: 3, title: "Климат", brand: "Климат", serial_number: "2165412315864",…}

2: {id: 8, category_id: 5, title: "New", brand: "New", serial_number: "2165412315864",…}
```

This is my code to proccessing this array

```
computed:{
        ...mapGetters('order', ['users', 'products',  'orders']),
    },
    methods:{
        getProducts(products)
        {

            const arr = products.map(c => c.title)
            console.log('titles: ', arr); //Debug
            this.options = arr
        }

    },
```

And here is the code for the multiselect

```
<multiselect v-model="formData.product" :options="options" :value="values" :multiple="true" :close-on-select="false" :clear-on-select="false" :preserve-search="true" placeholder="Pick some" label="name" track-by="name" :preselect-first="true">
                                            <template slot="selection" slot-scope="{ values, search, isOpen }"><span class="multiselect__single" v-if="values.length &amp;&amp; !isOpen">{{ values.length }} options selected</span></template>
                                        </multiselect>



mounted() {
        this.getProducts();
    },
```

Comment: Where do you call the `getProducts(products)` function?

Comment: In mounted but im have an error getProducts is not a function

Comment: Is the mounted call in the `<script>` or the `<template>` part?

Comment: this is a script part

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not sending your args by calling just `this.getProducts()`. You don't need to, just write `this.` in front of the computed value inside the method.

```
methods: {
    getProducts () {
        const arr = this.products.map(c => c.title)
        this.options = arr
    }
}
```